# Why my expression for coupon collector is giving wrong output

Tags: probability-theory, coupon-collector

```
   y=n*log(n)+0.50*n+0.50;
```

This is my expression but it is giving 36.32 for n=12 while it has to give 37.24/

edit:This is the problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem

Comment: No idea what the coupon collector is and why that should be 37.24... Could you add more details

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The formula is $E(T)=n\cdot log(n)+\gamma\cdot n+0.50+o(1)$, when $n \to \infty$

$\gamma\approx 0.577215664$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

If you use the constant for your calculations, then you will get your desired result.

Comment: Could you more elaborate on o(1) as how to use o(1) in computer program

Comment: @Beginner I really don´t know how to implement it in a computer program.

Comment: okay No problem

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), the exact expectation value for the coupon collector's problem is
$$ n \cdot H_n, $$
where
$$ H_n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} \right) $$
is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

For your problem, you have $n = 12$. So simply compute
$$ 12 \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{12} \right). $$
This gives the answer you're looking for.

When $n$ is large, the harmonic number $H_n$ (the big sum) can be approximated as
$$ H_n \approx \log(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + (\text{additional terms that are too small to matter}), $$ 
where $\gamma \approx 0.577215664$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Plugging in this approximation, the expected value for the coupon collector's problem is
$$ n \log(n) + \gamma n + \frac{1}{2}. $$
This is the equation you had (but with the correct $\gamma$). It also gives the answer you're looking for.